# Can masscan use the Nmap Scripting Engine?

Tags: nmap

There is a great tool:

https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan

that we can use if a bigger network need to be scanned for various aspects.

But, can the masscan use the Nmap Scripting Engine?

For example, the "File ssl-heartbleed"?

http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masscan cannot use NSE, since it is a different program entirely. However, it does have some advanced features like Heartbleed detection. See [the author's blog](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/04/using-masscan-to-scan-for-heartbleed.html) for more details, but here's the basic command-line:

```
masscan 10.0.0.0/8 -p443 -S 10.1.2.53 --rate 100000 --heartbleed
```